# Leadbolt Banner off-screen

Tags: android, sdk, banner, off-screen, leadbolt

My banners sometimes go off the screen. I am using the Leadbolt SDK 4.00a and Android 4.1 with the following code:

```
mAdView = new AdController(mActivity, "MY ID", this);
mAdView.setAdditionalDockingMargin(0);
mAdView.setAsynchTask(true);
mAdView.loadAd();
```

[Image 1 http://imageshack.us/a/img27/9539/sc20130117140203.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img27/9539/sc20130117140203.png)
[Image 2 http://imageshack.us/a/img690/8301/sc20130117140148.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img690/8301/sc20130117140148.png)

Anyone have the same problem?

Comment: can you tell me please how to get the ID of my AD. (i.e MY_ID in your case)

Comment: You need to create a Publisher account on LeadBolt. Then you have to add an application and retrieve the code from the site

Comment: Is it free to create an account in LeadBolt website?

Comment: i have same problem..

Comment: I have same problem, have you found any workaround...

Answer (score 1):

This can happen while Android is layouting the banner ad and it has not been fully loaded at that time.

I don't know if it's possible to bypass that problem because we don't have control over that ad view and the SDK doesn't allow to preload the ad.

I would suggest that you switch over to use HTML banner ads and interstitials. You have more control over where the ads need to be positioned, animate them and you don't need to use any advertising SDK (which may be black-listed by some security services).

Check out that post by me, if you have problems with resolution independence or opening HTML ad clicks in the native browser:

http://qa.leadboltads.com/questions/632/how-toandroid-make-html-ad-resolution-independent-and-open-in-native-browser

Comment: I really need to use the sdk, because I also want to use notifications. I noticed that this happens with version 4.0 of the SDK. With an earlier version it not happens.

Comment: You could try AdController.setLayout(RelativeLayout layout), but for me it doesn't work since SDK 4.0.

Another solution would be to use the HTML banners as I suggested and use the SDK for the notifications.